# thresholding to distinguish small features in noisy data

Tags: image, matlab

I'm wondering what type of *threshold* would work well for distinguishing features that are very small (small in the *xy* sense) in comparison with the full spread, if that makes sense. The `graythresh()` function in Matlab that uses the *Otsu* method doesn't work too well for my data. *Otsu* is a clustering method where I think the # of pixels should be similar in each class, which is not the case for me so when I employ it I get a threshold that is way too small and falls well within a lot of the background noise that remains even after filtering.

Comment: Can you post a sample image, and give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information to be really helpful.  What kind of features are you trying to extract?  What, exactly, are you trying to do?

I wouldn't really consider Otsu's method to be feature extraction, it just tries to seperate an image into foreground and background by pushing a grayscale image to a binary (only black & white image).

For finding actual "features" in computer vision you'd be better served by something like [Harris Interest Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_point_detection) - but this is a guess since I'm not sure what your final goal is.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at methods for unimodal thresholding (see [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V14-43P41GG-2&_user=789722&_coverDate=11%2F30%2F2001&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1358093327&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000043357&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=789722&md5=f7399ecf7ef96f80ef1f321549714b08) by Rosin for a method that works ok-ish).

However, straight thresholding of noisy images may not be the best approach. There are a number of better methods that have been developed for finding small features in very noisy images. [Here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5109713&tag=1)'s a link to a paper that discusses a variety of methods.